# Build Select HTML Options using Enum

Tags: elixir

Assuming  `map = %{"One" => 1, "Two" => 2,"Three" => 3}`

I'm trying to build a String for `select` options like:

```
<option value=1> "One" </option> 
<option value=2> "Two" </option> 
<option value=3> "Three" </option>
```

This is my current code:

```
options = Enum.reduce map, %{}, fn x, y ->
options = """
  <option value=#{x}>#{x}</option>
 """
end
```

But I get this error:

```
Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for 
{"One", 1 }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)'s function takes two arguments, one as the accumulator and the other as the element in the enumerable (which is itself a two-element tuple).

You are trying to interpolate the entire tuple (E.g. `{"One", 1}`) in the string, but it doesn't implement the String protocol and hence raises the error. You can try something like this:

```
Enum.reduce(map, "", fn {x, y}, acc ->
  "#{acc}\n<option value=#{x}>#{y}</option>"
end)
```

---

If you're using **Phoenix Framework**, it's better to use the [`select/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4) helper. Otherwise, another approach would be to use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and [`Enum.join/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#join/2) instead:

```
map
|> Enum.map(fn {x, y} -> "<option value=#{y}>#{x}</option>" end)
|> Enum.join("\n")
```

Comment: Thank You!. On an unrelated note, is there a better way of writing this?    `for %{"name" => k, "id" => v} <- Enum.reject(formated_response["plans"], fn(x) -> String.starts_with?(x["name"],["P","S"]) end),into: %{}, do: {k, v}`

Comment: Your code is incomplete, can you post that as a separate question with more details?